# ASP.net MVC tablesorter has clickable column headers but doesn't sort

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tablesorter

This is my first time posting a question on here so I am going to try to be thorough so that you have all the necessary information.

I am trying to use tablesorter to sort my table. Here's the code in question:

```
   @model MyAspApp.Models.Jackets

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Roster</h2>







<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Multi-model view attempt</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/theme.default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
</head>
  

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.tablesorter")
    <script type="text/javascript">

       

        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $("#Skaters").tablesorter(getSkaters());
            $("#Goalies").tablesorter(getGoalies());

        });
        

        

        

    </script>
}
<script>


        function getSkaters() {

            var allSkaters = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Skaters));
            for (var i = 0; i < allSkaters.length; i++) {

                $("#Skaters").append(
                    "<tbody><tr><td >" + allSkaters[i].First_Name + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Last_Name + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Number + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Position + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Goals + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Assists + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Points + "</td></tr></tbody>");

            }

        }




    function getGoalies(){

        var allGoalies = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Goalies));
        for (var i = 0; i < allGoalies.length; i++){

                $("#Goalies").append(
                    "<tbody><tr><td>"+allGoalies[i].First_Name+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Last_Name+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Number+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Wins+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Losses+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].OTL+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Save_+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].GAA+"</td> </tr></tbody>");

        }
    }

</script>


<body>

    <h1>Skaters</h1>
    <table id="Skaters" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th>
                <th> Number </th>
                <th> Position </th>
                <th> Goals </th>
                <th> Assists </th>
                <th> Points </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <h2>Goalies</h2>
    <table id="Goalies" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th>
                <th> Number </th>
                <th> Wins </th>
                <th> Losses </th>
                <th> OTL </th>
                <th> Save% </th>
                <th> GAA </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>


</body>
```

Now my table looks like this:

[Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kirXK.png)

As you should be able to see I can click on the column headers, in this case "Goals" is clicked but the table doesn't actually sort the data.

I have searched multiple different solutions on StackOverflow and nothing seems to be working. A lot of those solutions have involved configuring tablesorter with the uitheme and zebra widget but it seems that any time I switch from the default theme I lose my table formatting altogether.

(Yes, I have the necessary files and references included in my ASP project when I try to switch themes.)

Heck just for kicks I went to tablesorter's docs page and copied their whole configuration from their demo just to see if it would work and that had the same affect of losing all my table formatting.

So, I can't figure out what I am missing here and I would be so grateful if you all could help me figure this out. I am tired of searching and searching. Thanks. I hope I provided enough information.

Comment: It looks like a new `<tbody>` is being appended with each row. Move the `<tbody>` outside of your loop.

Comment: I can't believe that's all it took to fix this issue. I've been looking for a solution for days. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Add your solution as an answer, and I'll upvote it. I don't need any more points ;)

Comment: Sorry I kept forgetting to post the solution code until now. But I am still having trouble getting widgets to work properly. Anytime I add some widget configuration code I lose sorting functionality again. Ideas?

Comment: The selectors should include the `tbody`: `$("#Skaters tbody").append(...)` and `$("#Goalies tbody").append(...)`; If new content is, or widgets are, added dynamically, use [`$('table').trigger('update')`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#update) instead of calling `tablesorter` again.

Comment: Actually, if new widgets are added, use [`applyWidgetId`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#applywidgetid)

Comment: Dude thank you so much!!! My table looks so much more professional now! I love it.

Answer (score 1):

moved the tbody tags outside of the loops that populate my tables to the html declaration of the tables and that fixed the issue.

```
@model MyAspApp.Models.Jackets

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Roster</h2>







<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Multi-model view attempt</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/theme.default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
</head>
  

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.tablesorter")
    <script type="text/javascript">

       
        $(document).ready(function () {

         
            $("#Skaters").tablesorter(getSkaters());
            $("#Goalies").tablesorter(getGoalies());

        });

     

        

        

    </script>
}
<script>


        function getSkaters() {


            var allSkaters = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Skaters));
            for (var i = 0; i < allSkaters.length; i++) {

                $("#Skaters").append(
                    "<tr><td >" + allSkaters[i].First_Name + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Last_Name + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Number + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Position + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Goals + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Assists + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + allSkaters[i].Points + "</td></tr>");

            }

        }




    function getGoalies(){

        var allGoalies = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Goalies));
        for (var i = 0; i < allGoalies.length; i++){

                $("#Goalies").append(
                    "<tr><td>"+allGoalies[i].First_Name+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Last_Name+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Number+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Wins+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Losses+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].OTL+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].Save_+"</td>"
                            +"<td>"+allGoalies[i].GAA+"</td> </tr>");

        }
    }

</script>


<body>

    <h1>Skaters</h1>
    <table id="Skaters" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th>
                <th> Number </th>
                <th> Position </th>
                <th> Goals </th>
                <th> Assists </th>
                <th> Points </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    <h2>Goalies</h2>
    <table id="Goalies" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th>
                <th> Number </th>
                <th> Wins </th>
                <th> Losses </th>
                <th> OTL </th>
                <th> Save% </th>
                <th> GAA </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>


</body>
```